# How do I declare multiple variables instantiated by a function call returning multiple values in Go?

Tags: syntax, go, return-type, variable-declaration

Let's say I have a function:

```
func foo() (bool, string) { ... }
```

And then I wish to declare two variables `b` and `s`, initialized with values returned by the function call `foo()`. I'm aware I can do this using the "shorthand" syntax which omits type annotations:

```
b, s := foo();
```

However, I do not wish to use this shorthand syntax. I wish to use the `var` syntax with a variable name and expected type. I have tried this:

```
var b bool, s string = foo();
```

However, this gives me a syntax error. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `:=`? It's standard idiomatic Go.

Comment: A "I do not wish to..."-attitude with Go will become very painful in short time.

Comment: To be fair, there are reasons (which is why I asked). E.g. wanting an `io.Reader` variable that gets initialized from one of `os.Open` or if that fails from something else. In such cases I usually just do something like `var r io.Reader; var err error` then `r, err = os.Open(…)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most cases, the correct way to do this is to use the shorthand syntax. That's what it's for.

If you don't want to use the shorthand syntax, then you can use `var` syntax:

```
var b bool
var s string
b, s = foo()
```

or

```
var (
    b bool
    s string
)
b, s = foo()
```

There is no "shorthand var" syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. The Go Spec defines a [variable declaration](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) grammar as follows:

```
VarDecl     = "var" ( VarSpec | "(" { VarSpec ";" } ")" ) .
VarSpec     = IdentifierList ( Type [ "=" ExpressionList ] | "=" ExpressionList ) .
```

Variables in the `IdentifierList` can only have either one `Type` for all, or none. The best you can do is either

```
var b, s = foo()
```

or, if you want them at the top level of your package,

```
var (
    b bool
    s string
)

func init() {
    b, s = foo()
}
```